# How to do custom password restore in joomla?

Tags: joomla

I rewrote Joomla authorization using a plugin with `onUserAuthenticate` method to use custom service. Now i need to add custom password restore like question/answer (they already exists in db). Is there any event to fire on password reset or may be some other thing which could replace default password restore via email ?

Comment: You may get a more comprehensive answer from the new [Joomla StackExchange Beta site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified a Joomla version so I'll base my answer on the current 3.x series.

Joomla's authentication works via the plug-in's as you already know, but the front-end login is handled through a combination of the component `com_users` and module `mod_login`.

On the back-end there is also `com_login`, all of which work with the JAuthentication.

To work in conjunction with your restore you will need to create a component (e.g. `com_myauthenticator`) to present the front-end views. You may be able to do it in a `module` but apart from space considerations a Joomla `component` allows you to do much more without jumping through hoops.

The starting point [tutorial for Joomla 3 components is here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Introduction) and you can find more in the [Developers Portal](http://docs.joomla.org/Portal%3aDevelopers).